# Where should I post questions about API resources for sports?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking to find resources for sports API's to gather data. Would Stack Overflow be the correct place to ask a question like this? It's a programming need but not really a "software" problem to solve.

Comment: I was under the impression this should be the place to ask if a question is suitable. @Paulie_D thanks for the link to the help center I hadn't even looked.

Comment: To OP. Maybe (really not familiar with that site so YMMV, I suggest checking their help center) on softwarerecs? It's made for software recommendations. I would assume APIs fall there too.... But again, I'd say search their help center before posting

Comment: no you are entirely correct here. This is just me being unable to read a question this morning. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Patrice perfect thanks I'll go take a look. I briefly skimmed through the  sites but I did not think of that name to check.

Comment: Just FYI, because I've looked into this before, Stack Overflow is the right place to ask about scraping data from web pages if you don't find a suitable API.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm typing out my question over there as we speak and I was just thinking I may need to just scrape some of the info. Thanks

Comment: At the risk of giving a thanks-only comment, I want to thank you (especially as you appear to be a new user) for asking here before posting on the main site.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Web API recommendations appear to be on-topic on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). See [Are web API recommendations on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716) for more details. I'm not a regular on that site, so please consider spending a few minutes reading their [help articles](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) to verify that it is indeed the site you are looking for.

They seem to already have at least a couple of questions about Sports APIs:

- [Sports Matches Schedule API/SDK](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/41670)
- [sports feed API, free or paid](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/44772)

Check them out before posting your own, to avoid posting a duplicate.

Comment: Checking them out and it seems I may not get the answer I'm looking for. I may end up building my own just by scraping the data.

Comment: @Stevenfowler16 OpenData.SE, suggested in [Florian Brucker's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367151/99456), may turn out to be a better site for your question than SoftRecs.SE.

Comment: You may be correct. I'll try both and report back as to which is more suitable.

Comment: Users going to Software Recs should generally read this Meta post before posting: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/2481

Comment: Might it be worth asking at Meta https://opendata.stackexchange.com/if this is on topic there? That somehow feels more appropriate than SW recs.

Comment: Looking into both it seems Open Data would be a better choice for the question...though no suitable answers were found.

Answer (score 20):

As defined in in the [on-topic] section of the [help] center..

### No it would not be appropriate.

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 13):

Data API requests are also on-topic on [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) according to [their help center](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). They even have a [`sports`](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) tag.